# What Ubuntu can I run on my PowerEdge 840?

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, system-installation

So I recently got my hands on a old Dell PowerEdge 840 With a Intel Pentium D Processor with a whopping speed at 3.00 GHz, in the bios it says that the system memory is 1024 MB ECC DDR2 even though I should have 2GB..
Anyways, I've tried booting it up with Windows 8.1, Ubuntu Desktop 16.4 and Windows Server 2003, the only thing that actually went through the boot screen was the windows server, the other ones gave me an error saying "No boot device available" when trying to boot them, I would assume its because this machine doesnt support windows 8.1 and ubuntu desktop?
Im new to this so there might of been a few flaws in what I just wrote.

Comment: The problem is with the installation media and/or how you're trying to boot/install. Dell PowerEdge 840 is actually certified for Ubuntu.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2245040

Comment: @MichaelBay I looked at that thread and I did press CTRL + S but it didnt show me if I had raid ornot

Answer (score 0):

It was a hardware issue.
I got my hands on this machine just a couple of hours ago and the previous owner said that one of the DVD's arent working as they should, naturally I assumed it was the one that didnt have a broken front side but however that was not the case.
I got a ***pxe e61 media test failure*** which made me think "This is hardware related" so against all hope I plugged in the other DVD thinking "I've literally tried everything else, why not do this last thing?" and there we go, Ubuntu 16.4 started like a charm.
Take it from me, been dealing with computers for well over 14 years and I always check the hardware to begin with, dont do the same mistake as me. Good luck solving your issues!